# Using reflection to retreive a specific element in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

Lets say I have an array of Addresses

How can I filter addresses based on given string. Example if a property path has `Addresss.First()`, I want it to display the first element, or `Address.Last()` the last element.

ex:

```
var _propertyInfo = case.MainContact.GetType().GetProperty("Addresses");

XPCollection<BillingUnitContactAddress> buAddresses = (XPCollection<BillingUnitContactAddress>)_propertyInfo.GetValue(case.MainContact);

BillingUnitContactAddress buAddress = buAddresses.First(); //dont want to hardcode this
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the method that corresponds the provided name before. `Last` and `First` are all (extension-)-methods defined within the `Enumerable`-class in the `System.Linq`-namespace:

```
var first = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("First", BindingFlags.Static);
```

now you can invoke the method. However keep in mind extension-methods are just static methods, so you can set the first parameter of `MethodInfo.Invoke` to `null`:

```
var result = first.Invoke(null, myList);
```

Comment: your var = first line always returns null for me

Comment: @CoreyDubois Try with `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static`